Did Moses and Joshua wipe out the Canaanite tribes or were there terms of peace
I was confronted by an atheist who wanted to argue. His silly debate was that God loves ethnic cleansing which is false of course.
So did Moses and Joshua completely wipe out the Canaanite tribes or did they offer them a chance to leave or take up the 7 laws of Noah?

Would the ultimatum make it not an ethnic cleansing?

Job 1:21 The Lord gives and the Lord taketh away.

The Book of Judges clearly says that the Israelites allowed the natives to stay in the Holy Land:
-And the children of Benjamin did not drive out the Jebusites that inhabited Jerusalem; but the Jebusites dwell with the children of Benjamin in Jerusalem unto this day. [Judges 1:21]
-And Manasseh did not drive out the inhabitants of Beth-Shean and her towns, nor Taanach and her towns, nor the inhabitants of Dor and her towns, nor the inhabitants of Ibleam and her towns, nor the inhabitants of Megiddo and her towns; but the Canaanites continued to live in that land. [Judges 1:27]
-And Ephraim did not drive out the Canaanites who lived in Gezer; but the Canaanites lived in Gezer among them. [Judges 1:29]
-And Zebulun did not drive out the inhabitants of Kitron, nor the inhabitants of Nahalol; but the Canaanites lived among them… [Judges 1:30]
-And Asher did not drive out the inhabitants of Acco, nor the inhabitants of Sidon, nor of Ahlab, nor of Achzib, nor of Helbah, nor of Aphik, nor of Rehob;  but the sons of Asher lived among the Canaanites, the inhabitants of the land; for they did not drive them out. [Judges 1:31-2]
-And Naphtali did not drive out the inhabitants of Beth-Shemesh, nor the inhabitants of Beth-Anath; but he lived among the Canaanites, the inhabitants of the land… [Judges 1:33]
and finally:
-And the children of Israel dwelt among the Canaanites, the Hittites, the Amorites, the Perizzites, the Hivites, and the Jebusites. [Judges 3:5]


The Extermination of the Cannanites
Moshe didn't kill any Cannanites. He died before the invasion.

Joshua explicitly permitted some Cannanites, who had fooled him, to live, as well as the family of Rahab, who betrayed Jericho.
Apart from the Gibeonites, no Cannanites decided to become Noahides and enserf themselves to the Israelites.
Joshah 11:19

There was not a city that made peace with the children of Israel, save
the Hivites, the inhabitants of Gibeon; they took all in battle.

There is a midrash that the Girgashites fled Eretz Yirsoel before the conquest and God rewarded them with a place called "Afriki"
In the book of Judges we see references to Cannanite polities and failure of the various tribes to conquer them.

Does God like ethnic cleansing?
God would seem to dislike ethnic cleansing as we see that he wants to show mercy towards Nineveh and we have a midrash that God is upset when he drowns the Egyptians.

However, He did command the ethnic cleansing of the 7 nations and Amalek and the Midianites and so we would presume He likes it in some instances.
However, sometimes when God decrees an ethnic cleansing, He allows himself to be talked down, such as when Avraham tries to save Sodom or Moshe refuses to go along with His offer to destroy the Jews.
To conclude, Noam Chomsky is more uniformly against ethnic cleansing than God.
